# Unable to print an array in PHP

Tags: php, arrays

I am having a bit of trouble with this PHP code. I am not sure why it is printing `Array` 8 times. From what I see, it should be printing the contents of the array

The goal is to declare an array, using a `global`, define the array, assign it to another array and display the entire array.

```
$car_array = array( );
$array = array( );

create_array_cars ();
displayProduct ($array);    

function  create_array_cars (  )  {
    global $car_array;
    $car_array = array( );
    $car_array[] = "ID: 12345" ;
    $car_array[] = "ID: 45678" ;
    $car_array[] = "ID: 67890" ;
    $car_array[] = "ID: 89123" ;
    return $car_array;
    }

function displayProduct ($array) {
    global $array;
    for ($i=0;$i<4;$i++) {
        print "$array<br>"; }
    }

$array = create_array_cars();
print (displayProduct($array));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function displayProduct ($array) {
foreach ($array as $val) {
    print $val."<br>"; }
}
```

Comment: @user3367565: Using `global`s is not a very good coding practice. See [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22334694/1438393) for a bit more detailed explanation.

Comment: what is that global for !? Remove it!

Answer (score 1):

When PHP converts an array to a String it simply uses `Array`. You want to use [`print_r`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.print-r.php), [`implode`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php) or something similar.

Answer (score 1):

**Store the return value of the function in a variable:**

```
$array = create_array_cars();
displayProduct($array);
```

`create_array_cars()` returns an array — you need to store it in a variable for later use. `displayProduct();` takes an array as its argument and displays the contents inside it. Besides, it doesn't return a value — so we don't need to store the return value.

**Stop using `global`s when you don't need it:**

Globals are generally considered to be a bad coding style. You really don't want it here. Your function doesn't even need to deal with external data. You're only creating an array, **inside** the function, and returning it. So your code can just be:

```
function create_array_cars() {

    // Create the array
    $car_array = array(
        "ID: 12345",
        "ID: 45678",
        "ID: 67890",
        "ID: 89123"
    );

    // Return it
    return $car_array;
}
```

**Print the array *values* instead of trying to display an entire array:**

Printing *any* array always prints `Array`. You need to pick individual values in the array — since you're using a `for` loop which operates on the basis of numeric indices, you can do that with `$array[$i]`.

Also, I've changed `$i < 4` to `$i < count($array)`. This makes your code more *dynamic*. It'll work even if there are more than 4 elements in the array (not in this case though, as you're manually returning a pre-defined array in the other function).

The modified function will look like:

```
function displayProduct($array) {
    for ($i = 0; $i < count($array); $i++) {
        print $array[$i] . "<br />";
    }
}
```

Comment: Not that the argument $array for displayProduct is not needed if you use 'global $array'.

Comment: I also put the breaks on using globals. The assignment was asking to use globals though, that is why there was globals all over the place :P

Answer (score -2):

```
$car_array = array( );
$array = array( );

create_array_cars ();
displayProduct ($array);    

function  create_array_cars ()  {

    $car_array = array( );
    $car_array[] = "ID: 12345" ;
    $car_array[] = "ID: 45678" ;
    $car_array[] = "ID: 67890" ;
    $car_array[] = "ID: 89123" ;
    return $car_array;
    }

function displayProduct ($array) {
    //global $array;

        print_r( $array);
        echo "<bR>"; 

    }

$array = create_array_cars();
displayProduct($array);
```

not use global.  and print "$array
" is not correct... remove this " ".
or use print_r($VAR)